# Setting the minimum and maximum size of a window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, window

How does one set the maximum and minimum size of a window in OS X, using the Objective-C libraries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[theWindow setMaxSize:windowMaxSize];
[theWindow setMinSize:windowMinSize];
```

[NSWindow Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004151)

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 2 this would be:

```
myWindow.contentMinSize = NSSize(width: 600, height: 500)
myWindow.contentMaxSize = NSSize(width: 1024, height: 780)
```

Also according to the Apple docs, contentMinSize takes precedent over setMaxSize.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSWindow/contentMaxSize

Comment: How do I access `myWindow`?

Comment: let myWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: vc)
myWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
myWindow.title = "my window"
myWindow.contentMinSize = NSSize(width: 1024, height: 547)

Comment: max size of the content is a bit different than the max size of the entire window. 

`window.minSize = NSSize(width: 600, height: 500)` & 
`window.maxSize = NSSize(width: 1024, height: 780)`